# Android - Show a GPS Point in a owen Map

Tags: android, dictionary, gps, position, draw

i have the following Problem: I have a owen Map on my Device. Now i get the actual GPS-Position from GPS Provider and would draw this Point on my map. If i calculate the Following the DrawPoint is anywhere. What is wrong?

```
XMapScreen = 100;
YMapScreen = 200;
XMapGPS = 50.598886;
YMapGPS = 11.994318;

dLat = arg0.getLatitude();
dLon = arg0.getLongitude();

PointToDrawX = ((dLat * XMapScreen )/XMapGPS);
PointToDrawY = ((dLon * YMapScreen )/YMapGPS);
```

Comment: a map i have draw in Photoshop

Comment: Are you trying to convert gps coordinates into pixel in screen ?

Comment: Yes, that's would i do

Comment: @bastiZR then you need length and width of map ,find (dLat-XMapGPS) in distance then convert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the lat,lon coordinates of your ow(e)n map of left lower corner (SW) and right upper (NW).

Then you can calculate the X-Width = longitudinalSpan and the y-height = latitudinalSpan of your map.

Make sure your own map has North Up.
The rest should be simple.

But that only work for small scale Maps. 
Some 10 km, maybe a bit more.

Comment: OK, and if i have the span what should i do next?
Sorry for my bad english xD

Comment: For such a task a minum of mathematics is necessary: you should know how to lineary interpolate, how to calculate a conversion factor (e.g screenWidth/ longitdueSpan). try it first on paper: assume screenwidth and heigh = 100 * 100, and have a point at middle of map.

Comment: but how i musst do it?

Comment: Write a program that calculates the 70% value between 3 and 4. The correct answer is 3.7. If you can solve this, you are one step further.

Comment: Thast no poblem and now?
i think i stand on the hose

Comment: this is a linear interpolation: do the same to interpolate between leftX and right X (screen)

Comment: but how much percent?

like this:
 double dLatPerc = (dLatSpan*dGPSLat)/100;
        double dLonPerc = (dLonSpan*dGPSLon)/100;

Comment: isn't there any tutorial

Comment: better not use percent, instead values from 0 - 1; span = lonRight - lonLeft; leftRightFactor = (longitude - lonLeft) / span; screen x = screenXleft + screenwidth * leftRightFactor.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i have the following:

```
double dLat = arg0.getLatitude(); //GPS Position
    double dLon = arg0.getLongitude(); //GPS Position

    double latLeftLower = 50.58731;
    double lonLeftLower = 11.992316;

    double latRightUpper = 50.593509;
    double lonRightUpper = 11.998522;

    double dLatSpan = latRightUpper-latLeftLower;
    double dLonSpan = lonRightUpper-lonLeftLower;

    double dScreenWidth = ivMap.getWidth();
    double dScreenHeight = ivMap.getHeight();

    double dLatFactor = dScreenWidth/dLatSpan;
    double dLonFactor = dScreenHeight/dLonSpan;

    Log.i("GPS", "location changed: lat="+lat+", lon="+lon);
    double xDraw = ((dLat * dScreenWidth) / dLatSpan) / dLatFactor;
    double yDraw = ((dLon * dScreenHeight) / dLonSpan) / dLonFactor;
```

But thast's not right!?
Why?

Thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Looks better now, what is not right? Write a Junit  tets case, and try with all conrers and middel point oif screen.